# Cannot import DataFrame in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

1. I have installed pandas in my venv. The import statement `from pandas import DataFrame` is not recognized in Pycharm. DataFrame is underlined with red line. When I run the code, it works fine. Why DataFrame is not recognized.
2. Also suddenly, relative paths of local packages stopped working in PyCharm but code runs fine though.
   Absolute path also works fine.

I have tried setting project as "source code"  in settings but does not solve the problem.

Comment: Pycharm don't see side-packages from python. Try to correct path or check if you in venv?

Comment: I am in venv and pandas is installed. It seems like issue with pycharm settings because code runs fine without any import error but somehow in pycharm it shows unrecognized.  Same problem with relative import also in pycharm.

Comment: try to check Editor -> inspections tab in settings

Answer (score 1):

1. File -> invalidate Caches\Restart (did not work)
2. Removed .idea file and opened project again (did not work)
3. Pointed project to new venv with all installed dependencies (did not work)

Finally, uninstalled PyCharm and installed again. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might install the DataFrame on your default python environment.

To make sure you have installed on `venv` environment.

1- Activate your `venv`either form terminal or command-prompt by execuitng: `source ~/envs/venv/bin/activate`

2- Install pandas: `pip install pandas`

Now If you have installed correctly you will have a warning. Otherwise the package will be installed on your `venv`environment.